# How do I setup a public Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-api-client, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to upload files to a bucket on Google Cloud Storage, but I am having trouble figuring out how to set it up so that it is publicly writable and readable. In other words, I don't want to have to require authentication from the user in order to upload to the bucket. Does anybody know the steps to follow in order to set this up?

I would also like to know what I need to append to my request headers in order to upload files to this bucket. I am using the iOS API client, but if anybody knows what the raw headers are, I can probably figure out from there how to do it in iOS. At the moment, I am only including the following additional header: `x-goog-project-id`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For your first question, you can make your public your new uploaded objects with the following command that uses the [gsutil acl syntax](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl):

```
gsutil defacl ch -u allUsers:R gs://<bucket>
```

Now you need to give access to write to that bucket to everybody using the command:

```
gsutil acl ch -u allUsers:O gs://<bucket>
```

Regarding your other question, I'm not familiar with iOS but you can go to the bottom of [this page](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?&_ga=1.240157891.1329153032.1411458690#p/storage/v1/storage.objects.insert) and upload an object and you'll see the HTTP request that you can use in your code.

Also, there is [Google API Client Library for Objetive-C](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/) and it seems that with that library you can manage Google Cloud Storage [as per these files](http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Source/Services/Storage/Generated/).

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider using signed URLs (https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs ) instead of making your bucket publicly writable. Having a publicly writable bucket can be an opening to various forms of abuse, and also could result in your getting a surprisingly high bill if your bucket is discovered by someone on the Internet who then uploads large amounts of data to it.

Comment: I fully intend to use signed URLs, but for now I really just want to get a proof-of-concept working without having to implement something overly complex.