# Node.js: Google cloud storage credentials not loading in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

For my express server app, I have an `auth.json` file for my authentication which works fine in development.  In my deployed app the authentication is failing when I upload a file saying the error:

> Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.

Why is my authentication failing when it is deployed?

Currently all my buckets in this project are Public To Internet, and the roles allUsers and the Service Account Email both have full Storage Object Creator/Viewer/Admin roles.  The `auth.json` file is on the same hierarchical level as the app.js.

Here is my app.js code with all libraries and the post request that uploads the image.  It should be noted that the `uploadThumb()` function works every time, but the `uploadFile` is the one that causes the error shown below.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const _ = require("lodash")
const ejs = require("ejs");
const sharp = require('sharp');
const multer = require("multer");
const fs = require("file-system");
const imageThumbnail = require("image-thumbnail");
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage({keyFileName: "auth.json"});
const app = express();

//this writes the user submitted image to the local file system
var localStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    const imageDirect = req.body.categories + "/" + req.body.subcat.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + req.body.subcat.slice(1).replace(/ /g, "-") + "/";
    var dir = "./" + imageDirect;
    if(!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    }
    cb(null, imageDirect)
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    let tempImageName = file.originalname;
    req.imageName = tempImageName
    cb(null, tempImageName.replace(/ /g, "-"))
  }
});

var upload = multer({storage: localStorage});

app.post("/upload", upload.single("image"), (req, res) => {

//These define the paths and destinations dynamically
  let cat = req.body.categories;
  let subCatLiteral = req.body.subcat.split(" ");
  let subCat = ""
  for (i=0; i < subCatLiteral.length; i++) {
    var eachWord = subCatLiteral[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + subCatLiteral[i].slice(1);
    if (i < subCatLiteral.length-1) {
    subCat = subCat.concat(eachWord + "-");
    } else {
    subCat = subCat.concat(eachWord);
    }
  }
  let img = req.imageName.replace(/ /g, "-");
  let imgTitle = img.split(".")[0];
  let imagePath = cat + '/' + subCat + '/' + img


 //This is uploaded 1st
  async function uploadThumb() { 
    await storage.bucket(thumbs).upload(imgTitle + "-thumb.jpg", {metadata: {cacheControl: "no-cache"}, gzip: true, destination: cat + "/" + subCat + "/" + req.body.name.replace(/ /g, "-") + "-thumb.jpg"})
      uploadFile().catch(console.error);
      fs.unlinkSync(imgTitle + "-thumb.jpg")  //deletes file after upload 
  }


//This is uploaded 2nd, causing  the error
  async function uploadFile() {   
    await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(imagePath, {metadata: {cacheControl: "no-cache"}, resumable: true, gzip: true, destination: cat + "/" + subCat + "/" + req.body.name.replace(/ /g, "-") + ".jpg"})
      //deletes file after upload
      fs.unlinkSync(`${cat}/${subCat}/${img}`)
      fs.rmdirSync(`./${cat}/${subCat}/`)
      setTimeout(() => {
        fs.rmdirSync(`./${cat}`)
      }, 500)
    await listFiles().catch(console.error);
  }


 //This function starts the chain of uploads
 sharp(imagePath) 
     .resize(null, 300).toFile(imgTitle + "-thumb.jpg", function(err) {
       if (!err) console.log("image resized");
       uploadThumb().catch(console.error);
   })

  res.redirect("/upload#upload");
});
```

If anybody knows why this fails in production, or where exactly in the docs I can find the solution I would appreciate it.

**Here is the most recent error reporting to the passenger.log**

```
App 21701 output: Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
App 21701 output:     at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/home/kaylakos/nodevenv/rootdir/kayla/12/lib/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:157:19)
App 21701 output:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
App 21701 output:     at async GoogleAuth.getClient (/home/kaylakos/nodevenv/rootdir/kayla/12/lib/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:490:17)
App 21701 output:     at async GoogleAuth.request (/home/kaylakos/nodevenv/rootdir/kayla/12/lib/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:543:24)
App 21701 output:     at async Upload.makeRequest (/home/kaylakos/nodevenv/rootdir/kayla/12/lib/node_modules/gcs-resumable-upload/build/src/index.js:320:21)
App 21701 output:     at async Upload.createURIAsync (/home/kaylakos/nodevenv/rootdir/kayla/12/lib/node_modules/gcs-resumable-upload/build/src/index.js:145:22)
```

Comment: 1) Client Secrets is not related to your problem. 2) Your code is looking for a service account or the CLI `gcloud` auth credentials, based upon the error message.

Comment: Okay, because the client secrets is what fixed the issue in development, but now that the issue is back in production you're saying I need to do something with a service account? If you have a lead on what I should do or where I should look that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To start the search, can you please provide more debug output with line numbers and the files they are referring to?

Comment: @MrTech Updated the question, at the bottom

Comment: @MrTech is that what you're asking for?

Comment: Your application is using ADC (Application Default Credentials) which is the default situation for Google SDKs unless you specify otherwise. This means that you set up credentials on your development system but did not do the same on the production system. Read the link in the error message.

Comment: @JohnHanley  Thank you for the clarification.  I have read the page that the error message links to about a hundred times... do you think you can point me to the specific place in the docs that explains what I do in my case?  Do I set the env var in my code? In the SDK?  In the A2 hosting CLI?  I have a .json file I downloaded from google with my credentials and the path to it is correct according to A2 tech support.

Comment: Normally if you are deploying to a Google Cloud service (App Engine, Compute Engine, Cloud Run, etc.) you let the SDK use ADC. You then configure the default service account with the correct roles. What service are you deploying to? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts

Comment: I have developed and deployed the app outside of the google environment, using the google client library through node.js and downloading SDK to my local machine.  I used SDK to activate the service account credentials via the .json file google created under my service account.  I uploaded the code files to A2 hosting with CoreFTP.  The service account has the role of admin on the storage objects for the project, including object create/delete, which I set in the cloud console.

Comment: Then you will need to specify the service account JSON key filename when creating the client. Use code like this: `const storage = new Storage({keyFilename: "/fullpath/serviceaccount.json"});`

Comment: I tried doing this exact code, but it still gives me the same error.  I confirmed with A2 tech support that I have designated the correct file path, and they presume it is a credentials issue, not a file path issue.

Comment: The error `Could not load the default credentials` means that you are not correctly specifying the file to load the credentials from. Edit your question and show the code you are using and remove the code you tried. Then post the errors that match the code. Include the lines that show the libraries that you are using.

Comment: @JohnHanley Updated

Comment: I have found some information here (https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/issues/798). Are you using specific APIs like Cloud Vision? To get more insight can you please deploy your functions with additional logging enabled (DEBUG_AUTH)?